# Creating "negative" events for Firebase Audiences

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Example: I have a mobile app. Suppose I want to create an Audience in Firebase that represents "all app users who started but did not finish registration".

How can I achieve this? I can define a registration event, but that would create an audience of "all people who started registration [and possibly finished]".

Answer (score 0):

You can't define an audience of people who have not generate some event.  Membership in an audience can only be defined by the presence of events.  An audience will collect users from the moment it's created with those users who meet the given criteria.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

In firebase, you can create multiple events for your registration process. 
For example, if there are 3 screens you can create 3 events for each screen.

Now with the help of these events, you can analyze your data and even create a funnel to check where your users dropped while registering.

Check this for a more broader view.

[Firebase Events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events)

[Funnel in Firebase](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317523?hl=en)

[Audience in Firebse](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en)

The 3rd link clearly states that you need Events for generating funnel and getting data where your users dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can send an event "did not finish registration" you can't really define an even based audience for that. And even if you could, the devices would remain in the audience also after they register. However, there are few ways to tackle your problem. I assume having an audience is not your ultimate goal, but sending an event to those people that have not yet registered (or remotely changing something in their config). The options are:

1) Create an audience "Registered" with "Registered" event that is send immediately after registration occurs. Then send a notification with a rule "Audience" "does not include all of" "Registered". All but the ones in your audience receive the notification.

2) create a user property named "Registered" which is initially false. Make the app change it to true when registration happens. Then send a notification with rule "User property" "Registered" "contains" "false" (or = 0, depending on the type of your property). All that have not yet set the property to true will receive the notification.